# Unwanted caching of usercontrols and masterpages forcing iisreset

Tags: iis, user-controls, master-pages

My setup is a standard Windows 7, Visual studio 2008 and IIS 7.5 and I suffer from unwanted caching of usercontrols and masterpage files. Often but not always when I make changes in a usercontrol in Visual studio I have to reset the IIS to be able to see the changes I made in the HTML. I have also experienced this problem with IIS 6 and Windows server 2003. Anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you add some more details?

Answer (score 0):

How can you be sure that IIS is not picking up the new files, and that it isn't just your browser that is doing the caching?

Comment: I'm forcing my browser to request the latest version of all files.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the controls are recompiled when you update the `.ascx` file, but not when you update the `.cs` file.
In case your code is compiled into DLLs, it will not be updated until you recycle the IIS - you don't have to *reset* is (which takes all sites down), you can *recycle* your site's application pool.

Comment: If it works like you say I would never be able to see the changes I make in the HTML but I mostly do.

Comment: Sorry I missunderstood your answer.